# Issue in ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have set this query

```
 INSERT INTO pa_users (fname,lname,email,phone,fbid) VALUES ?
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fbid=VALUES(fbid),
    fname= VALUES(fname),lname= VALUES(lname),email= VALUES(email),phone= VALUES(phone)
```

And I'm passing this obj

```
{ 
   fname: 'Demo',
   lname: 'User',
   email: 'demo@facebook.com',
   phone: '6352417890',
   fbid: 'KHFDALJHGJDGWKGKDFDAFAJKLGEKLQAW' 
}
```

While run this query I got sql syntax error.

**Note:** fbid is not pk.

**Error:**

```
 code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
 errno: 1064,
 sqlMessage: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
 corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
 \'`fname` = \'Demo\', `lname` = \'user\', `email` = \'user@facebook.com\', 
 `phone` = \'63\' at line 1',
 sqlState: '42000',
 index: 0,
 sql: 'INSERT INTO pa_users (fname,lname,email,phone,fbid) VALUES `fname` = 
 \'Demo\', `lname` = \'user\', `email` = \'user@facebook.com\', `phone` = 
 \'6352417890\', `fbid` = \'KHFDALJHGJDGWKGKDFDAFAJKLGEKLQAW\'\n        ON 
 DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fbid=VALUES(fbid),\n        fname= 
 VALUES(fname),lname= VALUES(lname),email= VALUES(email),phone= 
 VALUES(phone)' }
```

Comment: Please share the exact syntax error message you are received.

Comment: @Arulkumar I have update in my question.

Comment: I'm passing data with param that's why I used ? in query. @newtover

Comment: It seems to be a UPDATE that an INSERT sentence ... `INSERT INTO $table ($column) VALUES ('$values')`

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting your query like

```
INSERT INTO table(a, b) values ('fgfg', 'fgfg') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
fbid=VALUES(fbid);
```

Comment: What about other columns ? Mysql will automatically update remian columns ?

Answer (score 0):

What is your primary or unique key? You don't need to update that value in case of duplication. Like if fbid is primary/unique key, query will be

```
INSERT INTO pa_users (fname, lname, email, phone, fbid) VALUES ?
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fname = VALUES(fname), lname = VALUES(lname), email = VALUES(email), phone = VALUES(phone);
```

Comment: In my case I have to check if fbid is exist then update the data otherwise add new data. In your answer you haven't used `fbid`. It will work ?